# bootstrap load collapse panel with ajax

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to load collapsable panels with ajax. I got it working, but my trigger fires on the a tag, so the ajax script is called when you open AND close the panel. It should not load it when you close the panel, this is overload..

My code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">    
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">First panel</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
              <div id="depUsers511"><!-- here users will be loaded through ajax --></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Second panel</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
              <div id="depUsers511"><!-- here users will be loaded through ajax --></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
$('#accordion a').click(function () {

    var collapse_element = event.target;
    alert(collapse_element);

    var href = this.hash;
    var depId = href.replace("#collapse",""); 

    var dataString = 'depId='+ depId + '&do=getDepUsers';
    $.getJSON(dir_pre + 'ajax/users.php?' + dataString, function(data) {
        $('#depUsers'+depId).html(data);
    });
 })
```

The ajax script returns the content of the div.
So, it works, but I'm looking for the correct way to fire the ajax load trigger... i think I need to use the "show.bs.collapse" event, but can't find out how to use this on a panel which contains more than one dynamic panel (with its own ID).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kind of solved it by adding a "open" class when loaded with data, and removing that same class if clicked when opened:

```
$('#accordion a').click(function () {
      if($(this).hasClass("panelisopen")){
          $(this).removeClass("panelisopen");
      } else {
          var href = this.hash;
          var depId = href.replace("#collapse",""); 

          $(this).addClass("panelisopen");

          var dataString = 'depId='+ depId + '&dep=1&do=getDepUsers';
          $.getJSON(dir_pre + 'ajax/users.php?' + dataString, function(data) {
              $('#depUsers'+depId).html(data);
          });
      }
  });
```

Not the best solution I guess, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e){
   var depId  = $(e.target).attr('id').replace('collapse','');
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of depending on element ID, and polluting it with numbers and do the string replacement and so, you can make use of `data` attributes:

```
<div class='collapse' data-dep-id="1" />
```

Then in JS:

```
var $elementId = $(e.target).data('dep-id')
```

And the same applies for Ajax URL and other attributes if needed.